# \dot horizontal alignment with amsmath

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, amsmath

I've a problem with horizontal alignment of the dot using `\dot` when including amsmath and using it on a custom command. A MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\ab}{a_b}
\begin{document}
$$ \dot a_b $$  
$$ \dot \ab $$  
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

While without including amsmath I get the behavior I want:

[image]

Is there a way to get the second behavior while still including amsmath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine：

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\olddot\dot 
\gdef\dot{\expandafter\olddot}
\begin{document}
\def\ab{a_b}
$$\dot a_b$$
$$\dot\ab$$
$$\dot{\ab}$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could just write `\gdef\dot{\expandafter\olddot}` right.

Comment: yah, thank you!

Comment: Is it also possible to get it to work if `\ab` is defined like `\def\ab{\ensuremath{a_b}}`?